# Storing data from a select tag to a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, drop-down-menu, while-loop

I'm trying to take information out of a form controlled by a select statement and store it in a string. The plan is to send the information gathered from the user via email, which I used PHP to do. I have an idea how to do it (a while loop that's controlled by how many lines are in the list,) but I can't quite gather the information.

Here's the loop:

```
    var empMessage = function(){
        messageString = "";
        var noEmp = $("#drpEmp option").length;
        var i = 0;
        $("#drpEmp").selector.index = i;    
            while (i < noEmp){
                $("#drpEmp").index = i;
                messageString = messageString + 
                "Name:              " + firstName.val + " " + MI.val + " " + lastName.val +  "<br/>" +
                "Business:          " + BusinessName.val + "<br/>" +   
                "Address:           " + address.val + "<br/>" +
                "                   " + city.val + ", " + state.val + " " + zip.val + "<br/>";
            }
            messageString = "<strong>Employee Information</strong><br/>" . messageString;
            i++; 
        }
        $("#stringHolder").val(messageString);
    }
```

Here's the JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xptxz7by/3/

I know I probably really off. I know I have the loop working and the list is getting counted, but I can't seem to retrieve the information. I'm also thinking I'm approaching sending the information wrong and there's probably a better way of doing it, I just haven't figured out how.

Comment: What is `$("#drpEmp").selector.index`? I don't understand what you're doing with that `while` loop.

Comment: All your `.val` should be `.val()`.

Comment: Why are you doing this in JS in the first place? Just submit the form to PHP and let it format the email.

Comment: @CaptObvious42 Ever thought of saving yourself a headache and just send a json to your php script? 

This way your php script is the only part that handles the logic for the email content. and that is sent is your form's data.

Answer (score 0):

The data you want is in the `Employee` object that you saved in each option's `.data()`, so you need to get that data and use the properties.

```
messageString = "<strong>Employee Information</strong><br/>";
$("drpEmp option:selected").each(function() {
    var employee = $(this).data("employee");
    messageString +=
        "Name:              " + employee.firstName + " " + employee.MI + " " + lastName +  "<br/>" +
        "Business:          " + employee.BusinessName + "<br/>" +   
        "Address:           " + employee.address + "<br/>" +
        "                   " + employee.city + ", " + employee.state + " " + employee.zip + "<br/>";
});
```